# How can I pass a PDO object to an Illuminate Capsule Manager

Tags: php, pdo, illuminate-container

I'm using Cartalyst's Sentinel user package as part of a user login library w/ a gui that I'm making. Sentinel uses Illuminate for the database.
So to set up the connection I have to do something like:

```php
        $capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
        $capsule->addConnection($dbInfo = [
            'driver'    => $package->get('DB.driver'),
            'host'      => $package->get('DB.host'),
            'charset'   => $package->get('DB.charset'),
            'collation' => $package->get('DB.collation'),
            
            'database'  => $package->get('DB.database'),
            'username'  => $package->get('DB.user'),
            'password'  => $package->get('DB.password'),
        ]);
        $capsule->bootEloquent()
```

Where `$package` is my own thing & is pretty self explanator. Just returns values for keys here.

Instead of using `$capsule->addConnection($arrayOfLoginInfo)`, I'd like to pass a previously instantiated PDO object. Something like:

```php
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addPdoConnection($pdo);
$capsule->bootEloquent()
```

But the [capsule manager](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Capsule/Manager.html) does not appear to have such a method.

I've never used Illuminate before, but I did some research a couple weeks ago & wasn't able to find a solution.

Comment: So you've determined the method you're looking for doesn't exist; what kind of answer are you looking for? Extend the class and create a method that does what you want.

Comment: I was just hoping there was an easy solution somebody else has done that just wasn't super obvious to an illuminate outsider.